# How can I create my desired string using a byte array?

Tags: android, string, arrays

I have the following byte array:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[] { (byte) -61, (byte) -61};
```

At first I convert it to String using the following line:

```
strResult = new String(bytes, "ISO_8859_1");
```

Then I convert it back to byte array using the following code:

```
byte[] myBytes = strResult.getBytes();
```

The content of myBytes is [-61, -125, -61, -125]

I have tested "US-ASCII" and "UTF-8" charsets. Each one returns a deferent string that none of them is [-61, -61].

**How can I create a String containing [-61, -61] bytes?**

**I mean I want to have a string when I use getBytes(); it returns [-61, -61] bytes. How can I create it?**

Answer (score 0):

You should use the same encoding to convert back again:

```
byte[] myBytes = strResult.getBytes("ISO_8859_1");
```

Basically the string *doesn't* maintain any record of the encoding originally used to create it - it's always just a sequence of UTF-16 code units. If you don't specify the encoding to use when converting a string to a byte array, it uses the platform default encoding.

Note that if you're trying to encode *arbitrary* binary data as text (i.e. you're not decoding something which is genuinely text in a particular encoding) then you shouldn't use these methods at all - you should use [`Base64`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html) to encode and decode safely.

Comment: No  I want to have string containing [-61, -61] bytes.

Comment: @breceivemail: A string contains *characters* - it doesn't contain *bytes*. It's very important to understand this, and not try to use strings to represent binary data. It's not really clear what you're trying to achieve - are you starting off with bytes which don't actually represent text (e.g. they're the data for an image)? Or is it (say) the contents of a text file?

Comment: I want to have a string when I use getBytes(); it returns [-61, -61] bytes. How can I create it?

thanks,

Comment: @breceivemail: That will depend on your default encoding - if it's UTF-8, there *is no such string*, because that's not a valid UTF-8-encoded sequence. Again, please explain the wider context. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: I tested the default UTF-16 and I noticed that it is not the default Charset.

Comment: in creating string, None of Charsets returns a string that I want. I want to have a string that when i Use getBytes(); returrns [-61, -61]

Comment: @breceivemail: What to you mean "the default UTF-16"? UTF-16 is used *internally* in `String`, whatever you decode from. Again, please state what you're trying to achieve. I *suspect* that you're approaching things inappropriately, and in a way which will lose information, but I can't tell for sure until you give me more of the bigger picture.

Comment: @breceivemail: From your original code, if you specify the encoding *when you call `getBytes()`* it will do what you want... but I still suspect you're doing the wrong thing. You still haven't explained why you think you need a string which you can call `getBytes()` on and receive that sequence. Calling `getBytes()` without specifying an encoding is almost *always* the wrong thing to do to start with.

Comment: my printer needs this special string to print correctly. A string when I use getBytes(); it returns [-61, -61] bytes

Comment: @breceivemail: What kind of printer is this? Are you really sending it a string and it's calling `getBytes()` on that string? Can you not send it the bytes directly? Whose code is it which is calling `getBytes()`? That's fundamentally the *wrong thing to do*.

Comment: Oh my god! can any body help me without any extra discussion. the question is obvious.

Comment: @breceivemail: Sorry, but you seem to fundamentally not understand what I'm saying. **What you're asking for is unreasonable.** Calling `getBytes()` without specifying an encoding will use the default system encoding. I suspect that's UTF-8 in your case. The byte array you're looking for is not a valid output from the system default encoding, therefore what you're asking for *cannot be done*. Furthermore, the call to `getBytes()` without an encoding is fundamentally inappropriate to start with.

Comment: This is my code

`strResult = "";`

  `byte[] bytes = new byte[] { (byte) -61, (byte) -61 };` `strResult = new String(bytes, "UTF-16");`
`byte[] bytes2 = strResult.getBytes();`

now bytes2 Is [-20, -113, -125]

Comment: @breceivemail: Yes, I'm not surprised. As I keep saying, you're not going to find a string such that `strResult.getBytes()` returns the data you want. It doesn't exist, assuming that the system default encoding as UTF-8 as I suspect it is. You need to avoid that encoding-less call to start with. Ideally, if you want to pass specific *bytes* to your printer, it needs to expose something for you to pass those *bytes* to it. Is this a printer with a public API I could examine?